# Steps to load a .txt file and convert the strings in it to usable data in a Sage notebook

Tags: sage

I am on a Mac with OS 10.11.6, and I'm learning the notebook interface for Sage 7.2. As a start, in a Sage worksheet I created a .txt file containing the string  `[1, 2, 3]` and saved it. I can open the text file directly and verify its contents just by clicking on it, but I can't yet do this in Sage.

I'd like to be able to open it and convert the string to a usable Sage object. I'd appreciate explicit instructions, assuming nothing at all about my Sage background. Thank you.

*Note:* The procedure to do what I just asked in the Sage documentation under "Saving and Loading Individual Objects" doesn't work in my environment (specs above.) I do `A = [1, 2, 3]`. Then I do `save(A, 'A')` and Sage returns a hot link for `A.sobj`. Then I hit the save-and-quit button. Then I hit "sign out." Then I sign back in and go to the worksheet where I did the steps I just described. I do `A = load('A')`. This is what Sage says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_sage_input_3.py", line 10, in <module>
    exec compile(u'open("___code___.py","w").write("# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\\n" + _support_.preparse_worksheet_cell(base64.b64decode("QSA9IGxvYWQoJ0EnKQ=="),globals())+"\\n"); execfile(os.path.abspath("___code___.py"))
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/7n/t9k4hfyn44s2qp7wxt479kn80000gn/T/tmpEa1OkK/___code___.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec compile(u"A = load('A')" + '\n', '', 'single')
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "sage/structure/sage_object.pyx", line 1032, in sage.structure.sage_object.load (build/cythonized/sage/structure/sage_object.c:11594)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A.sobj'`
```

Comment: This is also https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34915/load-contents-of-a-txt-file-into-a-sage-worksheet/

Comment: Yes. Hope there's no rule against asking on both platforms. Thought I might get an answer more quickly that way.

Comment: No problem, I just like cross-referencing for the sake of those searching in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in Finch's book. First a quote:

“We used a module called os from the Python standard library module to help us write code that can run on multiple platforms. A text file must have a special character to denote the end of each line in the file. Unfortunately, for historical reasons, each family of operating systems (Mac, Windows, and UNIX) uses a different end-of-line character. The os module has a constant called linesep that contains the correct character for the platform that the code is run on. We used the statement import os to make the module available, and accessed the constant using the syntax os.linesep. We also used the function os.path.join to join the path to the file name with the correct character for the current operating system.”

Excerpt From: Craig Finch. “Sage Beginner's Guide.”

Example using a file named "File2.txt" containing a single text character, '1':

import os path='/Users/barrybrent/.sage/sage_notebook.sagenb/home/**store**/2/21/212/2123/admin/19/data/' fileName='File2.txt' times = [] text_file = open(os.path.join(path, fileName), 'r') line = text_file.readline()

(Comment: is just a character string. To convert it a Sage object useful in computations:)

elements=line.split(',') times.append(float(elements[0].strip()))

(Comment: evaluate:)

times[0]

(Comment: Sage says"1.0". Now can we do arithmetic with times[0]?)

times[0]+1

Sage says "2.0"